# does buffer overflow still exist?

Tags: c, linux, security, buffer-overflow

I was watching a university lecture about buffer overflow, and the professor ended up saying

> even if we were able to fill the buffer with exploit code and jumped
>   into that code, we still can not execute it..

the reasons - he mentioned - are:

1. programmers avoid the use of functions that cause overflow.
2. randomized stack offsets: at start of program, allocate random amount of space on stack to make it difficult to predict the beginning of inserted code.
3. use techniques to *detect* stack corruption.
4. non-executable code segments: only allow code to execute from "text" sections of memory.

now I wonder, does buffer overflow attack still exist nowadays? or it is out-of-date.

*detailed answer will be very appreciated!*

Comment: The problem will *always* exist.

Comment: 1 is patently false. They *should*, but not all *do*. 2, 3, and 4 are OS- and architecture-dependent.

Comment: It's harder to exploit it, but the problem exists. Just because it's an old issue, it doesn't magically disappear as time goes by.

Comment: (3) is very unreliable in most implementations. (4) is incomplete: the idea is that memory sections are either executable or writable, but never both.

Comment: Non-executable stack doesn't save you. See return-to-libc/ROP-style techniques. Randomized library adresses help mitigate this, but often enough people find ways to predict these adresses using different vulnerabilities prior to triggering a stack or heap-based buffer overflow

Comment: There have been exploits with managed code and automatic memory management (e.g. Java) which would seem to indicate such problems continue.

Comment: 1. is basically same as saying "Programmers don't produce bugs." obviously that's not true.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Not all of us. There's a bunch of new programmers every day. Does our collective knowledge that `strcpy` is bad get disseminated to them magically? I don't think so.
2. *Difficult*, yes. Impossible, no. Any vulnerability that can be turned into an arbitrary read can defeat such protections trivially.
3. Indeed we can detect stack corruption, under certain circumstances. *Canaries*, for instance, may be overwritten, their value is compiler dependent, and they might not protect against all kinds of stack corruption (e.g. GCC's `-fstack-protector-strong` protects against EIP overwrite, but not other kinds of overrun)
4. W^X memory is a reality, but how many OS's have adopted it for the stack? That'd be an interesting little research project for your weekend. :) Additionally, if you look into return-oriented-programming (ROP) techniques (return-to-libc is an application of it), you'll see it also can be bypassed.

Comment: 4. Linux with proper kernel config and Windows with DEP enabled (default at least since Wimdows 7). So practically all modern OSes. Return-to-libc/ROP exist for a long time already to work around it. I think OS X is well behind in that regard, but I don't know for sure

Comment: To be more precise, hardware NX is supported in Linux since it became available and exec shield, pax etc can simulate it even if the hardware doesn't support it (e.g. on 32 bit Intels)